# clojure: O(1) time to get size of vector

Tags: clojure

### Context

```
(doc count)
-------------------------
clojure.core/count
([coll])
  Returns the number of items in the collection. (count nil) returns
  0.  Also works on strings, arrays, and Java Collections and Maps
```

### Question

Is count guaranteed to be constant time on vector?

If not, is there anyway to get the size of a vector in constant time?

### More Context

I actually want to get the list element of a vector, which I can do in O(1) with nth, assuming I know the vector size.

### EDIT:

I forgot to mention this. I need this to work on a *transient* vector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, count is always fast on a vector. But you can just call `peek` to get its last element.

Comment: My fault for not making this clear: it's actually a _transient_ vector. Since there isn't a transient list, I'm using conj!, pop! -- but I need a way to read the last element.

Comment: If it's a transient vector, it should be totally within your control what elements are in it or added to it (ie nobody should just pass you a random transient vector). So just keep track of which one is last separately, if it's hard to do otherwise.